# Get uniqe data source list from ArcGIS Pro project

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

How to get distinct data sources of layers and tables in ArcGIS Pro project?

```py
    aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
    maps = aprx.listMaps()
    for map in maps:
        print ('--------------------------------------------------------------')
        print (map.name)
        print ('--------------------------------------------------------------')
        layers = map.listLayers()
        tables = map.listTables()
        for layer in layers:
          print (layer.dataSource)
        for table in tables:
          print (table.dataSource)
```

Comment: Try creating a list of all of them, then use a set to remove duplicates - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists

Comment: This isn't an ArcGIS Pro question, or even a GIS question, it is a basic Python programming question, and a quick search for finding unique values in a list yields numerous answers.  The ArcGIS Pro aspect of this question is already answered [How to get a list of all data sources used in a ArcGIS Pro project? - GIS SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318002/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-data-sources-used-in-a-arcgis-pro-project)

Comment: I'm newby to Python, so I can't figure it out by myself. Tried to use set, but it didn't worked in ArcPy, so maybe it's not generel Python question, but ArcPy's.

Comment: Please don’t ask follow up questions in the same question. Ask a new question and link to the original as context, if it’s relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List [layer objects](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/layer-class.htm), extract their sources using `dataSource` property, convert to a set which can't have duplicates:

```
import arcpy

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")

layers = [] #A list to hold layer objects

for mp in aprx.listMaps(): #For each map in the project
    for layer in mp.listLayers(): #Find all layers
        layers.append(layer)
    for table in mp.listTables(): #And tables
        layers.append(table)
        
sources = [x.dataSource for x in layers] #Extract their sources
print(set(sources)) #Print unique sources
```

[image]